# Connecting to a Heroku PostgreSQL Database in an Android app?

Tags: android, postgresql, heroku

I wrote a ruby on rails app that I host on heroku and is used as a tool for creating data and storing it in the postresql heroku database

How do I do connect to it from an Android app for fetching data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach for this should be to use `REST` services to perform `CRUD` operations on your data, not directly connect from `Android` to the `database.

Comment: Which JDBC driver is best for android, 3 or 4?

Comment: @eoghanm as specified in the answer, you shouldn't connect to the database from android. Write a REST API app and deploy on Heroku and have your Android app interact with the REST API instead of the database.

Comment: Why can't we directly connect to the database ?

Comment: that's how you do this kind of stuff. mobile OSes don't have drivers to connect to remote databases